# How to stop displaying Symfony app under public directory?

Tags: symfony, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my Symfony app, which works under two links: on my root `example.com` and on subfolder `example.com/public`

How can I stop displaying app under link `example.com/public`? Is there any commands in `.htaccess` to do it?

My `.htaccess` in root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

In public folder I have `.htaccess` like this:
https://gist.github.com/alch/7766993

Answer (score 0):

In `/public/.htaccess` create an additional rule at the very top that redirects *direct* requests (ie. requests that have not been rewritten) back to the root.

You can't create a rule in the root `.htaccess` to do this, unless you enable/modify mod_rewrite inheritance, since when you request `example.com/public/` the mod-rewrite directives in the root/parent `.htaccess` file are completely overridden by the mod_rewrite directives in `example.com/public/.htaccess`.

For example:

```
# /public/.htaccess

# Redirect "direct" requests back to root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is *empty* for direct requests, which is what we test for here. (It is set to (string)`200` after the request has been successfully rewritten.)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file, so the capturing pattern `(.*)` excludes the `public` (parent) directory. The redirect back to `/$1` therefore excludes the `/public` prefix.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and clear your browser cache before testing.

---

This also resolves the issue of the canonical redirect (HTTPS and non-www) being bypassed when accessing the `/public` subdirectory directly (since, as mentioned above, the directives in the root are overridden). However, as written, the above would trigger two redirects in this scenario. One to root and a second to HTTPS and non-www. This is an edge case, but you could use an absolute URL in the above rule to avoid this. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```